# Framework not found BoringSSL-GRPC

Tags: flutter, firebase

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           215.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Framework not found BoringSSL-GRPC

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.